# JavaScript Subtle Crypto - No Padding for AES-CTR

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography

I am encrypting some data using `window.crypto.subtle` in JavaScript and I am trying to decrypt it in Python. From what I have read I was expecting Subtle Crypto to use PKCS#7 padding with AES-CTR, but it doesn't seem to be padding it at all, which is then causing me a problem as I am expecting padding in Python.

I have the following example code which encrypts the plaintext "plain" using a password of "password":

```
function bufferToHex(buffer) {
  return [...new Uint8Array(buffer)].map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join ('');
}


window.crypto.subtle.importKey('raw', new TextEncoder().encode('password'), 'PBKDF2', false, ['deriveKey']).then(function(key) {
  var salt = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(32));

  window.crypto.subtle.deriveKey({ name: 'PBKDF2', salt: salt, iterations: 10000, hash: 'SHA-256' }, key, { name: 'AES-CTR', length: 256 }, false, ['encrypt']).then(function(ekey) {
    var iv = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16));

    window.crypto.subtle.encrypt({ name: 'AES-CTR', counter: iv, length: 64 }, ekey, new TextEncoder().encode('plain')).then(function(ciphertext) {
      console.log('ciphertext is ' + bufferToHex(ciphertext));
    });
  });
});
```

However, this results in a 5 byte ciphertext `len(ciphertext) == len(plaintext)`, but I was expecting 16 bytes with PKCS#7 padding? The documentation seems a little light when it comes to padding. I am currently using `CryptoJS`, but I was trying to reduce my dependency on external modules and migrate to Subtle Crypto.

Comment: For stream cipher modes like CTR, no padding is needed and many libraries disable padding by default in this case (like the WebCrypto API).

Comment: I am implementing Ansible Vault encryption in a browser, which has decided to use PKCS#7 padding, so I don't really have a lot of options not to use padding if I want it to produce valid output. I did previously implement it using CryptoJS which will be my fallback, but I am hoping I can use a native browser implementation.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't enable padding with WebCrypto in case of CTR. If you need padding, you have to implement it yourself, which is not much effort.

Comment: There are several implementations on the web, e.g. [here](https://github.com/neeh/pkcs7-padding/blob/master/index.js#L12) is a PKCS#7 implementation for JavaScript that you can customize according to your needs (I haven't tested the library though).

Comment: Hmm, pad to *what*? In principle CTR is a stream cipher with a "block size" of one bit, or on byte oriented machines (i.e. all computers nowadays) one byte. You could also pad to the block size of AES of course, i.e. a multiple of 16 bytes. That one is both the most logical and the most moronic (because the padding is entirely unnecessary).

Comment: Ansible Vault pads it to the AES block size in their implementation.

Comment: From what I can see it looks fairly trivial to add padding. I just need to pad the plaintext so it is divisible by the block size using the number of padding bytes as the character code.

Comment: Libraries that do not implicitly disable padding for a stream cipher mode generally pad to the block size of the algorithm (i.e. 16 bytes for AES, e.g. CryptoJS). And yes, adding PKCS#7 padding is easy. Be aware, however, that PKCS#7 also pads if the plaintext already meets the length criterion (then it is padded with a full block, i.e. with 16 0x10 values). This must be taken into account, otherwise unpadding will generally fail for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close the loop for anyone else who is looking, I ended up with the following to apply PKCS#7 padding (based on the AES block size) before I encrypt the data:

```
function bufferToHex(buffer) {
  return [...new Uint8Array(buffer)].map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join ('');
}


window.crypto.subtle.importKey('raw', new TextEncoder().encode('password'), 'PBKDF2', false, ['deriveKey']).then(function(key) {
  var salt = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(32));

  window.crypto.subtle.deriveKey({ name: 'PBKDF2', salt: salt, iterations: 10000, hash: 'SHA-256' }, key, { name: 'AES-CTR', length: 256 }, false, ['encrypt']).then(function(ekey) {
    var iv = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16));

    var b_plaintext = new TextEncoder().encode('plain');
    var pkcs7_padding = 16 - (b_plaintext.byteLength % 16);
    var b_result = new Uint8Array(b_plaintext.byteLength + pkcs7_padding);

    b_result.set(b_plaintext);
    for (var i = b_plaintext.byteLength; i < b_result.byteLength; i++) {
      b_result[i] = pkcs7_padding;
    }

    window.crypto.subtle.encrypt({ name: 'AES-CTR', counter: iv, length: 64 }, ekey, b_result).then(function(ciphertext) {
      console.log('ciphertext is ' + bufferToHex(ciphertext));
    });
  });
});
```

Thanks to Topaco for the suggestions.